# VSTS website view Git tags

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops, git-tag

I am using Visual Studio Team Services with a project, using Git for the source control.

I am using the Git command line to tag the last commit with a version number before doing a release, then pushing it to VSTS, as follows:

```
git tag -a 1.2.4 -m "Some Message"
git push origin master --tags
```

This appears to complete successfully.

When I go to the "Code" tab on the VSTS website, I can see all of the commits in the branch history, but I cannot see the version tag that I created and pushed.

How can I view these tags on the VSTS website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting a branch, you can choose between "Mine", "All Branches", and "Tags". You want to look at "Tags".

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Note for anyone else reading this later, you click the dropdown next to the branch name ("master" in the graphic above), and then choose "Tags". I wish that when looking at a branch history, it actually had a column to show any tags associated with each commit, but this is at least functional.

Answer (score 1):

In the **History** Tab, you should also mark sure **Branch Updates** tab is selected -> click s-resize on the right of master branch -> select tag 1.2.4 in Tags tab -> then you will find the commit that tag 1.2.4 is on.

[image]